# Unix cat -n command implementation

Tags: c, unix, command

How do i include cat -n command in my program implementation
This is the problem with my program and i cant get it to print a new line number after every line so any suggestions on what i could do to rectify this

```
if(argv[1] == "-n")
{
    fd = open(argv[i],O_RDONLY);
    printf("%d\t",line);
    while(n = read(fd,&s,1) > 0)
    {
        if(s == '00')
        {
            line++;
            printf("\n%d\t",line);
        }   
        printf("%c",s);
    }
}
```

Comment: `'00'` is not a valid character literal.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it is maybe not what he intended to use but it is a valid character literal.

Comment: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
  int s = '00';

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: It's a valid character literal with an implementation-defined value, and it's almost completely useless.

Comment: `argv[1] == "-n"` isn't how you compare strings in C, use [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/), or better yet: [getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (n = read(fd,&s,1) > 0)
```

missing parentheses. `>` has higher precedence than `=`.

```
if(s == '00')
```

This is not how you detect an end of line. An end of line is typically a `'\n'` character in unix-like systems.

Comment: Why does he do `'00'` is it ascii value of `\n` or something ??

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan you should ask the OP not me. I have no idea why he is using `'00'`.

Comment: @JamesMorris I think there are more then one mistakes even `'0'` is not needed here.

Comment: Yep i did the mistake of taking the ascii value of null

Comment: @user2626335: No, you didn't. `'0'` is the digit zero; it has the value 48 on most systems. `'00'` is a multi-character constant; it has an implementation-defined value and is a mostly useless language feature. The null character (which isn't what you want here anyway) is written as `'\0'`.